# Get elements over opposite diagonal in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to solve a little problem with a matrix in R. I have the next matrix in R (`alfa`):

```
alfa <- matrix(1:9,nrow=3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    7
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

The opposite diagonal of `alfa` is filled of zeros. I would like to get in a new matrix all elements over this opposite diagonal (maybe the upper triangle over this diagonal). I wish to get a new matrix like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    0
[2,]    2    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0
```

Or like this matrix with `NA`:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    0
[2,]    2    0   NA
[3,]    0   NA   NA
```

Where the elements located down the opposite diagonal of `alfa` are zero or `NA`, as you can see. I have tried with code using `row(alfa)` and `col(alfa)` but I can't get the expected matrix, for example:

```
(row(alfa)+col(alfa)-1)%%ncol(alfa)!=0
```

And I got this result where both upper and down elements over opposite diagonal are `TRUE`:

```
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

But I only want the upper elements, and the rest elements should be filled with zero or `NA`.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: While the reproducible data is appreciated, wouldn't it have been simpler to provide a small matrix, like `matrix(1:9,nrow=3)`? The function should be the same, no?

Comment: Does this work? `m[(row(m) + col(m) - ncol(m) > 0] <- 0` where m is your matrix.

Comment: Yes @thelatemail sorry I will take your recommendation next time!!!

Comment: oops, missing `)`. Should be `alfa[(row(alfa) + col(alfa) - ncol(alfa)) > 0] <- 0` (changing `m` for `alfa`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
f <- function(mat, diag = 0, offdiag = NA){
  rev_vec <- seq(ncol(mat), 1)
  j <- mat[,rev_vec]
  j[lower.tri(j)] <- offdiag
  diag(j) <- diag
  j[,rev_vec]
}
```

You can specify if you want the off-diagonals to be NA or 0 by changing the offdiag parameter.

Comment: Thanks @agstudy.  I should have checked the function in a clean session.

Answer (score 3):

`lower.tri` almost does what you want, but you need to reverse the rows.

```
alfa[apply(lower.tri(alfa), 1, rev)] <- NA
```

Here, the matrix of the lower anti-diagonal is built, and used to select into `alfa` (vector indexing) for replacement.

`lower.tri` has a `diag` argument, which will also select the diagonal if set to `TRUE`.